# How to display the div of same class from list by clicking next button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having unanswered class of div in list. If i click next button it should hide the current div and go to the next div.

Here i am having 8 divs. The 3,5, 7, 8 having unanswered class. If i click next button from "3" div. It should toggle to "5" div.The remaining "3,7,8" should be display none.How i need to customize this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.tabs').tabs();
});
```

```css
.quiz-container h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

 .quiz-container .box{
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.quiz-container .box label{
 cursor:pointer;
}
.quiz-container .question {
  background-color: #170092;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 115%;
  color:#fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.quiz-container .question:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 35px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #170092;
}
.quiz-container .question span.question_number_quiz {
  background-color:#170092;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 40px;
}
.quiz-container .answers {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.quiz-container .answers .answer {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #727272;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.quiz-container .answers .answer:hover, .quiz-container .answers .answer.active {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #170092;
  border:1px solid #170092;
}
.quiz-container .answers .answer:hover span:not([class^="checkmark"]), .quiz-container .answers .answer.active span:not([class^="checkmark"]) {
  background-color: #170092;
}
.quiz-container .answers .answer.active span.checkmark {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 120%;
}
.quiz-container .answers .answer span:not([class^="checkmark"]) {
  background-color: #727272;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 40px;
}
.quiz-container button {
  background-color: #cb2127;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 110%;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.quiz-container button:hover {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.quiz-container button span {
  font-size: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: 10px;
}

.quiz-container{
 width:65%;
 margin:0 auto 39px;
}
.tabs .tab.completed_que a{
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#009933;
}
.tabs .tab.missedque a{
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#A50303;
}
.questiontabs .tab a.active{
   background-color: #fcfcfc;
    color: #212121;
 border:none !important;
 }
 .questiontabs .tab{
  height: 30px;
    line-height: 29px;
 }
  .questiontabs .tab a{padding:0 10px;color:#212121; border-radius:4px;}
.questiontabs a.active{
 border:none !important;
}

.questiontabs{
 background:none;
  margin-top:-27px;
}

.quiz-container .indicator{
 display:none !important;
}
.icon{
   border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 10px;
}
.active .icon{
 background:#fcfcfc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}
.attempted .icon{
 background:#009933 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-color: #009933;
}
.not-attempted .icon{
 background:#A50303 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-color: #A50303;
}
.test_status li{
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:10px;
}
.questiontabs_test{
 visibility:hidden;
}
.questiontabs .completed_que.disabled a{
 opacity:0.4;
}
.questiontabs .completed_que.disabled a:hover{
 cursor:not-allowed;
 color:#fff;
}
.questiontabs .completed_que.disabled .active{
 background-color:#009933;
 color:#fff;
}
.question_images img{
 display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;
}
.question_action_form p{
 margin:0px;
}
.instructions li{
 list-style:inside;
}
.instructions ol li{
 list-style-type:decimal;
 line-height:35px;
}
.instructions p{
 font-size:13px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quiz-container">
                 <p>Question 1 of 5</p>
                     <div class="question1 questions" id="questions1">
                         <div class="question box">
                            <p><span>1.</span> Which one of the five is least like the other four ?</p>
                          </div>
                         <ul class="answers">
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>a</span>Shark</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>b</span>Deer</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>c</span> Cow</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>d</span> Dog</p>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                          <div class="aligncenter control_sec  pull-right">
                           <input type="submit" class="btn red waves-effect" value="Skip" id="next_1">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn red waves-effect" value="Submit" id="submit_1">
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="question2 questions" id="questions2">
                         <div class="question box">
                            <p><span>2.</span> Which number should come next in the series ?   1 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 5 - 8 - 13</p>
                          </div>
                         <ul class="answers">
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>a</span>8</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>b</span>21</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>c</span> 26</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>d</span> 31</p>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                          <div class="aligncenter control_sec  pull-right">
                           <input type="submit" class="btn black waves-effect" value="Previous" id="back_1">
                           <input type="submit" class="btn red waves-effect" value="Skip" id="next_2" onClick="next()">
                             <input type="submit" class="btn red waves-effect" value="Submit" id="submit_2">
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="question3 questions unanswered_que" id="questions3">
                         <div class="question box">
                            <p><span>3.</span> If you rearrange the letters "ANICH", you would have the name of a/an: </p>
                          </div>
                         <ul class="answers">
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>a</span>Country</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>b</span>Ocean</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>c</span> State</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>d</span> City</p>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                          <div class="aligncenter control_sec  pull-right">
                           <input type="submit" class="btn red waves-effect" value="Next" id="next_4" onClick="next()">
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="question4 questions" id="questions4">
                         <div class="question box">
                            <p><span>4.</span> I'm a male. If Albert's son is my son's father, what is the relationship between Albert and me? </p>
                          </div>
                         <ul class="answers">
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>a</span>he is my brother</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>b</span>he is my uncle</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>c</span> he is my father</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>d</span> he is my sister</p>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="question5 questions unanswered_que" id="questions5">
                         <div class="question box">
                            <p><span>5.</span> Nearby Priests" - If these letters are rearranged, they create the name of which person? </p>
                          </div>
                         <ul class="answers">
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>a</span> A famous scientist </p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>b</span> A pop princess </p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>c</span> A football player</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>d</span> A baseball player</p>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                          <div class="aligncenter control_sec  pull-right">
                           <input type="submit" class="btn red waves-effect" value="Next" id="next_4" onClick="next()">
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="question6 questions" id="questions6">
                         <div class="question box">
                            <p><span>6.</span> Nearby Priests" - If these letters are rearranged, they create the name of which person? </p>
                          </div>
                         <ul class="answers">
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>a</span> A famous scientist </p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>b</span> A pop princess </p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>c</span> A football player</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>d</span> A baseball player</p>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                          <div class="aligncenter control_sec  pull-right">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn red waves-effect" value="Next" id="next_4" onClick="next()">
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="question7 questions unanswered_que" id="questions7">
                         <div class="question box">
                            <p><span>7.</span> Nearby Priests" - If these letters are rearranged, they create the name of which person? </p>
                          </div>
                         <ul class="answers">
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>a</span> A famous scientist </p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>b</span> A pop princess </p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>c</span> A football player</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>d</span> A baseball player</p>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                          <div class="aligncenter control_sec  pull-right">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn red waves-effect" value="Next" id="next_4" onClick="next()">
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="question8 questions unanswered_que" id="questions8">
                         <div class="question box">
                            <p><span>8.</span> Nearby Priests" - If these letters are rearranged, they create the name of which person? </p>
                          </div>
                         <ul class="answers">
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>a</span> A famous scientist </p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>b</span> A pop princess </p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>c</span> A football player</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="answer box">
                              <p><span>d</span> A baseball player</p>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                          <div class="aligncenter control_sec  pull-right">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn red waves-effect" value="Next" id="next_4" onClick="next()">
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                       <div class="row MT20">
                        <div class="col s12">
                          <ul class="tabs questiontabs">
                            <li class="tab completed_que disabled"><a href="#questions1">1</a></li>
                            <li class="tab completed_que disabled"><a href="#questions2">2</a></li>
                            <li class="tab missedque"><a class="active" href="#questions3">3</a></li>
                            <li class="tab completed_que disabled"><a href="#questions4">4</a></li>
                            <li class="tab missedque"><a href="#questions5">5</a></li>
                             <li class="tab completed_que disabled"><a href="#questions6">6</a></li>
                              <li class="tab missedque"><a href="#questions7">7</a></li>
                               <li class="tab missedque"><a href="#questions8">8</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>
                      <div class="aligncenter test_status">
                       <ul>
                         <li class="active"><span class="icon"></span>Active Question</li>
                            <li class="attempted"><span class="icon"></span>Attempted</li>
                            <li class="not-attempted"><span class="icon"></span>Not attempted</li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
               </div>
```

Comment: Could you please add some `CSS` too so that we can replicate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your HTML pass `this` as a parameter i `next()` function.. like this..

`<input type="submit" class="btn red waves-effect" value="Next" id="next_4" onClick="next(this)">`

then use this code.. this should work.

```
function next(_this){
    var _el = $(_this).parents('div.active');
    var _id = $(_this).attr('id');
    $(_el).removeClass('active');
    $(_el).css('display','none');
    $(_el).closest('div').nextAll('.unanswered_que').eq(0).css('display','block').addClass('active');
    $('li.tab').removeClass('active');
    $('[href="#' + _id + '"]').addClass('active');
}
```

> Note: You will still have to manipulate this further as per your requirement

Comment: How to remove the previous class active?

Comment: Edited the code.. added this `$(_el).removeClass('active');`
now it should remove class.

Comment: Can i use it for pagination too?

Comment: I need help in pagination. Can you please help in that